# TF-IDF using in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

i am trying to use TF-IDF in pandas with data set content two columns first column it content text data and the another one it content categorical data  looks like blow

```
                summary                                 type of attack
```

unknown african american assailants fired seve...         Armed Assault
    unknown perpetrators detonated explosives paci...      Bombing
    karl armstrong member years gang threw firebom...     Infrastructure
    karl armstrong member years gang broke into un...      Infrastructure
    unknown perpetrators threw molotov cocktail in...       Infrastructure

i want to use tf-idf to convert the first column and then use it to  build the mode for prediction of the second columns that content the attack type

Answer (score 0):

I helped you to process your df into X and y to be trained with a short example.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = {'summary':['unknown african american assailants fired',
'Armed Assault unknown perpetrators detonated explosives','Bombing karl armstrong member years gang threw'],'type of attack':['bullet','explosion','gang']}

#tfidf
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

tf = TfidfVectorizer()

X = tf.fit_transform(df['summary'])

#label encoding
le = LabelEncoder()

y = le.fit_transform(df['type of attack'])

#your X and y ready to be trained
print('X----')
print(X)
print('y----')
print(y)
```

Output

```
X----
  (0, 9)    0.4673509818107163
  (0, 4)    0.4673509818107163
  (0, 1)    0.4673509818107163
  (0, 0)    0.4673509818107163
  (0, 15)   0.35543246785041743
  (1, 8)    0.4233944834119594
  (1, 7)    0.4233944834119594
  (1, 13)   0.4233944834119594
  (1, 5)    0.4233944834119594
  (1, 2)    0.4233944834119594
  (1, 15)   0.3220024178194947
  (2, 14)   0.37796447300922725
  (2, 10)   0.37796447300922725
  (2, 16)   0.37796447300922725
  (2, 12)   0.37796447300922725
  (2, 3)    0.37796447300922725
  (2, 11)   0.37796447300922725
  (2, 6)    0.37796447300922725
y----
[0 1 2]
```